# Avoding unnecessary updates In Update Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

In our application,Many pages includes "update" and when we update a table,we update unnecessary  columns,which dont change,too.
 i want to know that is there a way to avoid  unnecessary column updates?We use stored procedures in .net 2003.In Following link,i found a solution but it is not for stored procedures.

http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/04/25/tip-15-how-to-avoid-loading-unnecessary-properties.aspx

Thanks

Comment: It was my understanding that the smallest unit of work for a Database was a row and that it cost the same to update one column as it did to update them all.  I believe the only exception to this might be tables that contain text/ntext or blob columns.

Comment: not necessarily true.  if those columns have foreign keys & indexes, their could be alot more work needed to update a given row

Comment: my question is which rdbms?  if it is sql 2008, a MERGE statement may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was working at a financial software company, performance was vital. Some tables had hundreds of columns, and the update statements were costly. We created our own ORM layer (in java) which included an object cache. When we generated the update statement, we compared the current values of every field to the values as they were on load and only updated the changed fields.

Our db was SQLServer. I do not remember the performance improvement, but it was substantial and worth the investment. We also did bulk inserts and updates where possible.

I believe that Hibernate and the other big ORMs all do this sort of thing for you, if you do not want to write one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can really only accomplish this with a good ORM tool that generates the update query for you.  It will typically look at what changed and generate the query for only the columns that changed.

If you're using a stored procedure then all of the column values get sent over to the database anyway when you call the stored procedure so you can't save there.  The SP will probably just execute a run-of-the-mill UPDATE statement.  The RDMS then takes over.  It won't physically change the data on disc if it's not different.  It's smart enough for that.

So my answer in short:  don't worry about it.  It's not really a big deal and requires drastic changes to get what you want and you wont even see performance benefits.

Comment: that is totally not true.  most db engines will execute the update regardless.  their is still transaction tracking, change logging(if implemented), index updates and foreign key checks.  Updating unnecessary columns can definately have an impact, especially if those columns are indexed, even worse if they are part of the clustered index.

Comment: I believe Hibernate/NHibernate will do that out of the box.  It checks to see if an object is "dirty" (changes made to its properties) and will then create its own SQL statement to update the appropriate columns.  Granted, you also get the extra overhead of running an ORM framework, but if the framework is not on the same server as the database, this might help.